# betareg package for R 2.15.0

Tags: r

I had been using betareg previously on an older version of R (2.13 I think) prior to upgrading to version 2.15.0 (I'm running Ubuntu so I simply added the UCLA mirror to my sources.list.) Now things don't work. Here's a sample dialogue with the prompt:

```
> require(betareg)
Loading required package: betareg
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘betareg’
> install.packages("betareg")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/tim/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.sixsigmaonline.org/src/contrib
Warning message: 
package ‘betareg’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)
```

I'm not really sure what to do. Ideally I would be able to use this package in 2.15 (as I'll soon be working on a remote server using it - I am not admin.)  However, I would appreciate hearing of any fix that comes to mind. Thanks.

edit: Sorry to the CrossValidated folks for mixing things up.

Comment: No need to apologize, Tim: the migration occurred because we felt you would get a good answer more quickly here on SO, which has a large and highly qualified community devoted to the ins and outs of `R`. CrossValidated is always interested in `R`-related questions that need statistical/data mining answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proably need to look at a different mirror, since package betareg passes all package checks.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_betareg.html

(When I tried the mirror you offered with my browser I got a 404 message for the packages directory.)

Comment: Cool - for future reference, the mirror CA 1 worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: In particular, it takes time for updated versions of packages to migrate to all mirrors. I believe your original install.packages would have eventually worked without switching mirror sites.

Comment: @Wayne: The entire ../packages/ directory was unavailable at the mirror in question. The link that was offered was 404ed and then you get an access-forbidden error when you go upstream and try to access the ../packages/ directory. SixSigmaOnline appears to be having major quality control problems w.r.t. CRAN mirroring..